# What is the minimum UK visa processing time if I have to apply very urgently?

Tags: visas

I have to apply for a Tier 4 visa (UK) from Pakistan.  The program start date on my CAS letter is July 17th 2018.  Because of some reason I will submit the visa application on 1st July.

Will I get the visa decision from the consulate in 2 weeks, or can I apply for a UK visa two weeks before the travel date?

Comment: Apply for priority processing and 2 weeks are more than enough for that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Will I have to pay additional charges with the visa fee for priority processing?

Comment: I'm sorry I just noticed that this is not available for your case. *The Priority Visa service is currently not available to customers applying for a work or study visa in any Points Based System (PBS) category, including Tier 1, 2, 4 and 5 visas.* https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/pakistan/user_pay_services.html#4

Comment: My university advisory replied me that I may need to apply for a fast track visa service. But I think no such option is there in the online application system

Comment: Moreover on my CAS letter the mentioned start date is 17th July 2018. But there is another date mentioned too That is registration date: 23 July 2018

Answer (score 1):

[Tier 4 (General) student visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-4-general-visa)

> You’ll usually get a decision on your visa within 3 weeks. You can check [visa processing times](https://www.gov.uk/visa-processing-times) for your country.

The processing times search for Karachi for Points Based System Visas suggests a minimum time of 5 days, but only for a small percent of the applications. The vast majority take 10-15 days.

Note: the processing times tool is in beta and, while the Tier 4 guidance links to it, the only PBS option is Tier 2. Karachi was selected as an example; Lahore and Mirpur can also be chosen.